Regression strategies for predicting a binomially distributed, count outcome: Poisson, Negative Binomial, and Logistic Models with Offsets
Data Description:
I am working with a dataset of 100 hens, represented across four columns:
ID: Numbers 1 through 100. 
Age: Each hen's age.
EggCount: Number of eggs laid per hen, with a range from 0 to 20.
ChickCount: Number of chicks hatched from these eggs, also ranging from 0 to 20.
Question:
My goal is to develop a statistical model that can predict the number of chicks based on the age of the hen, potentially incorporating other variables that are not listed here for simplicity. I am seeking guidance on the best approach to model this data.

Here below, there are some approaches I considered. However I have some doubts about their suitability as I explain below.
Notes: 
Modeling Approaches that I considered:

Poisson or Negative Binomial Regression:
I am considering whether a Poisson or negative binomial model would be appropriate for this analysis, particularly with an offset for EggCount. The models under consideration are:

glm(ChickCount ~ Age + log(EggCount), family=poisson(), data = DF) 
glm(ChickCount ~ Age, offset=log(EggCount), family=poisson(), data = DF) 
glm.nb(ChickCount ~ Age + log(EggCount), data = DF) 
glm.nb(ChickCount ~ Age, offset=log(EggCount), data = DF)

Given that chick emergence from each egg can be modeled as a Bernoulli event and is not a rare occurrence, I have doubts  about the suitability of these models.

Logistic Regression with Data Restructuring:
Another approach I considered is to reformat the dataset into a long format where each egg represents a separate observation with a binary outcome (0 or 1, depending on hatching success). This structure would allow for the inclusion of hen ID as a random effect in a logistic regression model. This model is such as:

    glm(DidChichComeOutofEgg ~ Age + 1|ID, family=binomial(), data = DF) 

Concerns I have with this approach include:
a. Potential bias due to hens with more eggs disproportionately influencing the model.
b. Possible confounding of the effects of age and hen ID, since eggs from the same hen will have the same age.

I can state the problem also as; 
The probability of chick per egg (p) is affected by Age. And the ChickCount is binomially distributed with parameters EggCount and p. But i don't know the true approach for modelling.

$$
\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times \text{Age}
$$
$$
\text{ChickCount} \sim \text{Binom}(n=\text{EggCount}, p=p)
$$

Are there any concerns about selection? If older chickens who aren't producing enough eggs are systematically removed from the data, that can bias the age curve up.

No, there is no selection bias. As i wrote, Age is only one predictor among the set of many predictors for the event of chick hatching out of egg. for simplicity, I represent only the Age variable.

Do you also use egg characteristics for the prediction, like size or weight?

No there is no egg characteristics. Only characteristics regarding the hen such as age, weight, color, egg and chick count from this hen. I have data of 100 rows for 100 hen as i told.

The logistic approach seems to me to answer a fundamentally different question.  It models chicks per egg instead of chicks per hen. Which you are interested in is a substantive question. The answer depends on what you are going to do with the info. E.g. are you deciding whether to do something to the hens, or the eggs?

A veterinarian uses characteristics such as age, weight, and color of hens to estimate chick counts for a given hen with known number of eggs laid. My aim is two fold. Initially, a simpler model estimates chick counts based on these hen attributes and egg count of the hen. Understanding this model helps solve a more complex problem: calculating the minimum number of eggs the hen needed needed based on her attributes for at least one chick with an 80% probability.

For the solution of the second step, if i can model the probability of chick come out of egg (p) based on the individual properties of hen, then i can easily calculate the probability of the hen to have at least one chick by using 1 - (1-p)^n formula.

Your logistic method 2 would result in an estimated probability for an egg to produce a chicken. But you should glmer instead of glm to model the random hen effect:
library(lme4)
m2 <- glmer(DidChichComeOutofEgg ~ Age + (1|ID), family=binomial(), data = DF)

You could then calculate the probability for e.g. an "average" hen (random effect equals zero) to produce 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 chickens (or at least one chicken, etc), given a total of e.g. 4 eggs and given the age of the hen, of course. And maybe more relevant, you could then show that the proportion of eggs producing chickens increases (or decreases) with age.
Instead of your method 2, your method 3 would give exactly the same results:
m3 <- glmer(cbind(neggschicken, neggsnochicken) ~ Age + (1|ID), family=binomial(), data = DFcounts)

For your method 3 to work, your data frame DFcounts should contain the columns  neggschicken and neggsnochicken, referring to the number of eggs that turned into chicken and the number of egges that did not. Note that this model m3 also contains the random hen effect, although there is only one observation per hen! Method 3 seems more straightforward in your case, because there are no predictors on the "egg" level.
Further, I also would prefer the binomial distribution, as opposed to the poisson and the negative binomial, because the number of "successes" has an upper limit.
Random effect models are often used for longitudinal data, where the number of observations differs across "respondents". In research among pupils in schools, the number of pupils in schools typically can differ. The effect of a higher level "respondent" or "school" variable is much less influenced by such an unbalanced situation than would be the case in a basic regression model without random "respondent" or "school" effect.
The age effect could always be biased because you omitted relevant "hen" variables in your model. That is however a general feature of all kinds of regression models. As long as this is not the case, there is no bias in the age effect.
